Why does Swag init only generate "general API information"?
Issue Description
Swaggo fails to recursively parse Swagger comments in Go files when using the swag init command with multiple directories and the --parseDependency and --parseInternal flags. Only the comments in the main file specified with the -g flag are parsed, while the comments in other files within the specified directories are not considered.
Files that contain swaggo comments are internal/transport/http/v1/auth.go, internal/transport/http/v1/trip.go, and cmd/app/main.go
Repo structure is here
commands I have run:
swag init -d cmd[enter image description here][1]/app/ -g main.go --parseDependency --parseInternal
swag init -d cmd/app/,internal/transport/http/v1 -g main.go --parseDependency --parseInternal
All the commands above produces the same result
Results
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate swagger docs....
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate general API Info, search dir:cmd/app/
2023/06/29 17:45:38 Generate general API Info, search dir:internal/transport/http/v1
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mProfCycleWrap at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mprof.go:165:7, reflect: call of reflect.Value.Len on zero Value
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const locb at /Users/ikramkamat/go/GoWorkSpace/pkg/mod/github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2@v2.0.8/internal/characters/utf8.go:183:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const hicb at /Users/ikramkamat/go/GoWorkSpace/pkg/mod/github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2@v2.0.8/internal/characters/utf8.go:184:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t1 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:29:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const tx at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:30:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t2 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:31:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t3 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:32:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11100000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t4 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:33:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11110000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const t5 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:34:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b11111000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const maskx at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:36:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask2 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:37:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00011111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask3 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:38:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00001111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const mask4 at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:39:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b00000111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const locb at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:46:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10000000": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 warning: failed to evaluate const hicb at /usr/local/go/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go:47:2, strconv.ParseUint: parsing "b10111111": invalid syntax
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create docs.go at docs/docs.go
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create swagger.json at docs/swagger.json
2023/06/29 17:45:40 create swagger.yaml at docs/swagger.yaml

generated swagger.yaml
basePath: /api/v1
host: localhost:8000
info:
  contact: {}
  description: REST API for InnoCoTravel App
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  title: InnoCoTravel API
  version: "1.0"
paths: {}
securityDefinitions:
  ApiKeyAuth:
    in: header
    name: Authorization
    type: apiKey
swagger: "2.0"

Comments in one of the files other than cmd/app/main.g
package v1

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/itoqsky/InnoCoTravel-backend/docs"
    "github.com/itoqsky/InnoCoTravel-backend/internal/core"
)

//  @Summary        SignUp
//  @Tags           auth
//  @Description    create account
//  @ModuleID       signUp
//  @ID             create-account
//  @Accept         json
//  @Produce        json
//  @Param          input   body        core.User   true    "sign up info"
//  @Success        200     {integer}   integer
//  @Failure        400     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        404     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        500     {object}    errorResponse
//  @Failure        default {object}    errorResponse
//  @Router         /auth/sign-up [post]

func (h *Handler) signUp(c *gin.Context) {
    <other code>

swag version
e.g. 1.8.12
go version
e.g. 1.20.2
OS
OSX

In my case, it was due to the whitespace between the function declaration and its annotation.
As is
// CreateOrder godoc
//  @Summary        Create a new order
//  @Description    Create a new order with the input payload
//  @Tags           orders
//  @Accept         json
//  @Produce        json
//  @Param          order   body        Order   true    "Create order"
//  @Success        200     {object}    Order
//  @Router         /orders [post]

func CreateOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var order Order
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&order)
    prevOrderID++
    order.OrderID = strconv.Itoa(prevOrderID)
    orders = append(orders, order)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(order)
}


It wasn't working due to the whitespace between //   @Router         /orders [post] and func CreateOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) 

To be
// CreateOrder godoc
//
//  @Summary        Create a new order
//  @Description    Create a new order with the input payload
//  @Tags           orders
//  @Accept         json
//  @Produce        json
//  @Param          order   body        Order   true    "Create order"
//  @Success        200     {object}    Order
//  @Router         /orders [post]
func CreateOrder(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var order Order
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&order)
    prevOrderID++
    order.OrderID = strconv.Itoa(prevOrderID)
    orders = append(orders, order)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(order)
}

So how about trying this one, removing the whitespace?
...
//  @Router         /auth/sign-up [post]

func (h *Handler) signUp(c *gin.Context) {
...

into
...
//  @Router         /auth/sign-up [post]
func (h *Handler) signUp(c *gin.Context) {
...

